# Substring SQL Query Variable

Tags: python, sql, variables, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query the Database for a sub-string, I am substituting a string variable from a form for the query. It is giving me a syntax error.

This is the error:

```
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%'sometext'%'
[SQL: SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%%''%(form)s''%%']
[parameters: {'form': 'some'}]
```

This is the query:

```
books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%:form%'", {"form":form.search.data}).fetchall()
```

If I use an actual string in the SQL query it works. It is an issue with using a variable. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: can't you add the `like` operators outside the SQL statement using `format`? i.e inside your params dictionary

Comment: which db you are using ???

Comment: @scaisEdge using postgres, the CONCAT function  worked

Comment: @aws_apprentice I could have built the string outside the query, got it to work with CONCAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using concat  for avoid quote and windchar issue

```
books = db.execute("SELECT * 
      FROM books 
      WHERE title LIKE concat('%',:form, '%')" , 
     ........
```